# Point to a function with an already - provided arguments

Tags: c, function, function-pointers, invoke, void-pointers

I want to point to a function with arguments, except the argument is provided before invoking. It is not possible for me to provide the arguments while invoking, as I am dealing with different function with different amounts of arguments. The specific function I want to invoke without arguments is `exit()`, so if there is version of the function exit with no arguments (not matter what the return code is) it will solve my problem as well.
This is what I am trying to do:

```c
/*Point to exit() with argument provided 1. Am  not trying to call the function just yet.*/
void *func = &exit(1);
/*Dereference and invoke the function. Provide no argument as they were already provided.*/
*(((void)()) func)();
```

Comment: Can you use `void my_exit1(void) { exit(1); }   ... func = my_exit1;`?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I thought about that solution, But it seem messy to create a function just for that

Comment: No, C doesn't support closures.

Comment: @KamilCuk and is there any exit function with no arguments?

Comment: You'll need to write your own `exit_1()` function and use that.

Comment: At some point prior to calling `*(((void)()) func)();` the `exit()` arguments (just one arg in this case) needs definition.  Could  set globally and then use `void my_exit(void) { exit(global_my_exit_arg); }` (and risk the usual global variable gripes)